# perl regular expression explanations

Tags: regex, perl

I am completely lost on this line of perl code

```
$path =~ s|^\./|~/|; #change the path for prettier output
```

I am assuming it has to do with regex. I have some understanding of regex but i just cant seem to figure this one out.

what is `=~` and why is there s and how does regex expressed in perl?

Comment: Try [`man perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Actually, `perldoc perlrequick`'s [Search and replace](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) section might be an easier read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`=~` is a binding operator. It applies the substitution (hence the `s`) to the variable `$path`. The substitution has two parts - a regular expression and the replacement. They are delimited by the `|` character in this case. The regular expression is

```
^\./
```

`^` stands for the beginning of the string. `\.` stands for a literal dot, `/` stands for itself. So, `./` at the beginning of the string is replaced by `~/`.

Answer (score 4):

the `=~` binds a scalar expression to a pattern match, the `s` is for replacement

what its doing is matching start of line with a ./ then replacing it with a ~/

as far as the | pipes, you can use any non-whitespace character to delimit parts of the regex you can use ^ or & or q or m or { whatever.. most people use / for readability but for cases where you might match on / use something else.

Hope this helps.